# Node-red HTTP POST parameters

Tags: node.js, http, curl, node-red

Can someone help me translate this working curl command into a node-red POST command?

```
curl -X POST http://URL -H "Authorization: 123123123" -d "subjectUid=789789789"
```

Here's my partially working function node which creates the parameters and pushes to a http node:

```
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers={ 
    'Authorization':  '123123123'
};

msg.payload = {};
msg.payload={ 
    'subjectUid': '789789789'
};

return msg
```

The auth token is accepted, but the server replies that the subjectUid is not set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What content-type does the server accept?

Comment: Not sure about the server specs, but the default setting of the node-red doesn't seem to be compatible, unlike curl's defaults. Your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be that by default the post message will forward on the JSON representation of the `msg.payload` object, what you want is the form encoding.

Try adding the following header:

```
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers={ 
    'Authorization':  '123123123',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

msg.payload = {};
msg.payload={ 
    'subjectUid': '789789789'
};

return msg
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Could you also edit your answer to suggest the equivalent syntax to make it work using simpler inject and/or change nodes? It doesn't make much sense to use the full-fat function nodes just to inject a string into the flow.